# Eloquent replace model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

Is there any way to "replace" and return a different Eloquent model in model events, in the creating event more specifically?

My use case for this would be to check if a model already exists with some given parameters, drop the new and use the older one for processing in other events.

Returning false from the creating event is not an option as this would prevent firing any other model and custom events.

Also, I'm not working with controllers, I'm using nuwave/lighthouse for my API and I'd like to avoid using custom resolvers for this.

Comment: And by sooner you mean?

Comment: In my experience putting critical business logic in events, make your code really hard to understand, if at some point anybody else than you needs to understand it.